# Pretty URL in Yii2 LinkPager with custom params

Tags: yii2

I need `LinkPager` to create page URL like `/site/page/1/job/2/order-price/3/order-exp/4/`.

The route works fine with the URL manager, but `LinkPager` ignores this route and creates URL with `?foo=bar` parameters.

```
$rules = [
    'site/page/<page:\d+>/job/<job_id:\d+>/order-price/<min_price:\d+>/order-exp/<experience:\d+>/' => 'site/index'
];   

'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'suffix' => '/',
        'rules' => $rules,
    ],
]

$pagination = [
    'pageSize' => 1,
    'forcePageParam' => true,
    'pageSizeParam' => false,
    'params' => [
        'page' => $this->page,                        
        'job' => $this->job_id,
        'order-price' => $this->min_price,
        'order-exp' => $this->experience
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect parameters names. If your pattern is `site/page/<page:\d+>/job/<job_id:\d+>/order-price/<min_price:\d+>/order-exp/<experience:\d+>/` then parameter names are:

- `page`,
- `job_id`,
- `min_price`,
- `experience`.

You should either change your rule to:

```
site/page/<page:\d+>/job/<job:\d+>/order-price/<order-price:\d+>/order-exp/<order-exp:\d+>/
```

Or adjust param names in pagination config:

```
[
    'pageSize' => 1,
    'forcePageParam' => true,
    'pageSizeParam' => false,
    'params' => [
        'page' => $this->page,                        
        'job_id' => $this->job_id,
        'min_price' => $this->min_price,
        'experience' => $this->experience,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Still not working. I have changed param names in pagination config, and the rule config. Now all of the have the same name, but result is still the same.

Comment: did you tried adding the rule `"/"=>"site/index"` in your `urlManager`, @P.Shatalov